# Does Parquet preserve row order of a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

```
val rows = sqlContext.sparkContext.textFile("in.txt")
val df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df1.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("df.pq")
val df2 = sqlContext.read.parquet("df.pq")
```

Why `df1.collect()` and `df2.collect()` have different row orders? I'm running Spark 1.5.1 in local mode.

Comment: I don't think spark guarantees order in any case. Think of it as SQL.

Comment: At least does `textFile("in.txt").collect()` preserve the order of "in.txt"? I couldn't find anything in docs.